# Getting angle of rotation of a SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode that runs a SKAction that rotates it forever. So basically, I have the following code:

```
[myNode runAction:[SKAction repeatForever:[SKAction rotateBy:M_PI*2 duration:1]]];
```

At some point, I'd like to access the current angle at which the node is at. Something along the lines of:

```
float currentAngle = myNode.currentAngle;
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could go about doing this? I have tried searching the docs but haven't found any "angle" or "currentAngle" property for a SKSpriteNode.

Comment: you're looking for zRotation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try This... It will give you rotation angle.

```
NSLog(@"%f",myNode.zRotation);
```

Comment: Perfect. The zRotation seems to be what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Generate Node Angle store in One Variable  like, (**float myNodeAngle)**.then when ever you want to Access then pass it.